# Reassemble multiple capture groups from Ansible regex_search

Tags: regex, ansible

I retrieved a version string into 'myvar' like 00001.00022.00333 which I would like to move into my dict as 1.22.333

The regex is pretty simple, but I am unable to reassemble the capture groups.  Can someone explain how to fix this?

```
set_fact:
  cacheable: yes
  mydict: "{{ mydict | combine({ 'version': myvar | regex_search('0*(\\d+)\\.0*(\\d+)\\.0*(\\d+)', '\\1.\\2.\\3') }) }}"
```

The output of the code above is [ "1" ] (an array) instead of "1.22.333".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *regex_replace*. No need to escape backslash if you put it into single quotes. For example,

```yaml
  mydict: "{{ {'version': myvar|regex_replace(md_regex, md_replace)} }}"
  md_regex: '0*(\d+)\.0*(\d+)\.0*(\d+)'
  md_replace: '\1.\2.\3'
```

gives

```yaml
  mydict:
    version: 1.22.333
```

The same result can be achieved without regex. For example,

```yaml
  mydict: "{{ {'version': myvar.split('.')|map('int')|join('.')} }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    myvar: 00001.00022.00333

    mydict: "{{ {'version': myvar|regex_replace(md_regex, md_replace)} }}"
    md_regex: '0*(\d+)\.0*(\d+)\.0*(\d+)'
    md_replace: '\1.\2.\3'

    mydict2: "{{ {'version': myvar.split('.')|map('int')|join('.')} }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: mydict

    - debug:
        var: mydict2
```

---

Q: ***"Show a working example for this all in a task, including vars in the task."***

A: Simply put the variables into the *vars* at the task's level

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ {'version': myvar|regex_replace(md_regex, md_replace)} }}"
      vars:
        myvar: 00007.00088.00999
        md_regex: '0*(\d+)\.0*(\d+)\.0*(\d+)'
        md_replace: '\1.\2.\3'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    version: 7.88.999
```

---

See:

- [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)
- [7.3.2. Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style)
- [7.3.1. Double-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#731-double-quoted-style)

Comment: i can not get the capture groups to work at all, e.g. if i put `\1` in the _replace var, OR even if i put `\\1` in regex_search 2nd param as in OP, still no joy. It would be great if somebody can show a working example for this all in a task, including vars in the task, not at the playbook level, because I cant see how this works.

Comment: I added an example. See the links to understand the difference between the single-quoted and double-quoted styles. I prefer to put a regex as a single-quoted string into a separate variable. It's pretty nasty very soon when you start nesting the styles and escaping special characters.

Comment: Thank you.  thats very helpful and I agree.  Also I think i figured out what I was doing wrong, I was underestimating the capture groups, at the same time as my regex was capturing more than I thought it would be.  After adjusting `_regex` it started to make more sense.  Make sure your regex doesnt capture more that you want, or you will get back more than you want.. Thank you!! Also I think I need a better regex site, this one doesnt seem to be cutting it https://regex101.com/